# Can I add additional Jetpack Compose New Project Templates to Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, ide, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using Android Studio.  Was Arctic Fox version and just upgraded to Bumblebee (2021.1.1).

I'm learning Jetpack Compose and would like more project templates.  Current project Phone and Tablet templates shown in image below.

**The IDE only has one new project template for compose: the Empty Compose Activity template.  Is there a way to download (free or at some cost) others?**

Thank you, Jason

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can find and download many compose projects for free in Google's android official repository:

https://github.com/android/compose-samples

There is also a beautiful blog post with video and an app that you can find almost all the code you need to get started. It is about all the components you can find with Jetpack Compose according to material guidelines:

https://material.io/blog/jetpack-compose-catalog

There are not any other templates inside Android Studio about Jetpack compose. As you have one activity - no fragments. No need for Google to show you different ways of creating an app. I do not believe you will find any templates very soon - this might change of course when Jetpack Compose become mature...

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  Those are helpful, but I'm looking templates that get loaded into that New Project area.  For instance, there are nearly a dozen Java-based templates (Bottom Navigation Activity, Full Screen Activity, etc).  Is there a way to get other Kotlin Compose ones into this area?

Comment: I have updated my answer... I hope you find it useful.